# What would be the best way to implode this associative array with keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a box model array

```
Array
(
    [padding] => Array
        (
            [padding-top] => 0px
            [padding-right] => 0px
            [padding-bottom] => 0px
            [padding-left] => 0px
        )

    [margin] => Array
        (
            [margin-top] => 0px
            [margin-right] => 0px
            [margin-bottom] => 0px
            [margin-left] => 0px
        )

    [border] => Array
        (
            [border-size] => 0px
            [border-style] => solid
            [border-color] => #ff6600
        )

)
```

And I need to output the following

```
padding-top : 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;

margin-top : 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;

border-size : 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ff6600;
```

I started with this

```
$box_model          = array();
foreach($box_model_array as $key => $value){


    $box_model[$key] = $key.':'.implode(';',$value).'';         

}


return implode('',$box_model);
```

so I ended up missing the second array index.

What would be the fastest way to get the desired result?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$box_model = array();
foreach ($box_model_array as $group => $styles) {
    foreach ($styles as $name => $value) {
        $box_model[] = "$name: $value;";
    }
    // If you really need the space in between the groups.
    $box_model[] = "";
}
$box_model = implode("\n", $box_model);
```